# jQuery: "data-target" toggle function – show only one content area

Tags: javascript, jquery

In general, my code (below) works. But: If you click at first "Link 1", and then for example "Link 2", only the content for Link 2 should be visible.

How is it possible to code that?

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $($(this).data("target")).toggle();
  // hide all other content areas
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  cursor: default;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left {
  background-color: azure;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left">
  <ul>
    <li data-target=".one">Link 1</li>
    <li data-target=".two">Link 2</li>
    <li data-target=".three">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="content one">Content for Link 1</div>
  <div class="content two">Content for Link 2</div>
  <div class="content three">Content for Link 3</div>
</div>
```

Would be very thankful for help! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to keep the ability to `toggle` the one you clicked, you can use

```
var target = $($(this).data("target"));
$(".content").not(target);
target.toggle();
```

to find all the content divs except the target one.

If you just want to show the clicked one then you can hide all the others, (as provided in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63620860/2181514)).

Updated snippet:

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".content").not(target).hide();
  target.toggle();
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  cursor: default;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left {
  background-color: azure;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left">
  <ul>
    <li data-target=".one">Link 1</li>
    <li data-target=".two">Link 2</li>
    <li data-target=".three">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="content one">Content for Link 1</div>
  <div class="content two">Content for Link 2</div>
  <div class="content three">Content for Link 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thaaaaanks!<3<3<3

Answer (score 1):

You're targetting a single `<div>` each time... there's nothing in your code to "reset" the other ones.

Try this, which first hides all the `<div>` elements, and then shows your selected one...

```
$("li").click(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $($(this).data("target")).show();
})
```

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $($(this).data("target")).show();
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  cursor: default;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left {
  background-color: azure;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left">
  <ul>
    <li data-target=".one">Link 1</li>
    <li data-target=".two">Link 2</li>
    <li data-target=".three">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="content one">Content for Link 1</div>
  <div class="content two">Content for Link 2</div>
  <div class="content three">Content for Link 3</div>
</div>
```

Note, if you need the content to disappear if you click the `<li>` a second time, this will not work, as it will always show the item you've clicked.

If you need it to disappear, see the [answer by freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63620860/930393)